# FileNet - Data to be copied exceeds space available error

Tags: corba, filenet-content-engine, ibm-jdk, filenet-cpe

some other team is calling our FileNet custom app for searching documents. I believe some of the users are facing intermittent failure because we are getting tickets(although none of the user has reported this issue) for the error below and I tried validating our service with different scenarios and they all worked but I don't know what's causing this error. any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<stackTrace> 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession.throwException(EJBSession.java:1122) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession.throwException(EJBSession.java:1045) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl._getObjects(EJBSession.java:650) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl.getObjects(EJBSession.java:575) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession.getObjects(EJBSession.java:471) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.util.SessionHandle.getObjects(SessionHandle.java:346) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.callGetObjects(Session.java:132) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeGetObject(Session.java:340) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.getObject(Session.java:354) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.DispatchEntries.FetchObject_28(DispatchEntries.java:907) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.ObjectStoreImpl.fetchObject(ObjectStoreImpl.java:1643) 
at com.filenet.api.core.Factory$ClassDescription.fetchInstance(Factory.java:21761) 
at ecm.service.p8ceservices.implementation.integration.SearchP8ObjectAdapter.retrievePropertyDefinitions(SearchP8ObjectAdapter.java:352) 
at ecm.service.p8ceservices.implementation.integration.SearchP8ObjectAdapter.integrate(SearchP8ObjectAdapter.java:158) 
at ecm.service.p8ceservices.implementation.integration.ContentEngineAdapter.execute(ContentEngineAdapter.java:37)
</stackTrace>


</exception><exception name="java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" message="Data to be copied (length 2124) exceeds space available (480)" sequence="0" guid="sfr2mx3l:jewe2wkf:00000000:00000121"><source class="com.ibm.rmi.util.buffer.SimpleByteBuffer" archive="" vendor="" version="" /><stackTrace> 
at com.ibm.rmi.util.buffer.SimpleByteBuffer.write(SimpleByteBuffer.java:166) at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ClientRequestImpl.reInvoke(ClientRequestImpl.java:489) 
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:637) at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1377) 
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:695) at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1407) 
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:484) at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejbstubs._Engine_Stub.getObjects(Unknown Source) 
at com.filenet.apiimpl.transport.ejb.EJBSession$EJBImpl._getObjects(EJBSession.java:638)</stackTrace>
```

Comment: what is the java version?

Comment: CPE: 5.2.1.7, WAS: 8.5, Java: 8

Comment: looks like it is the issue with Java ORB. SimpleByteBuffer is not able to fit in the header and the body payload. Better you open a PMR with IBM

Answer (score 1):

It could be the following issue:

ClientRequestImpl.reInvoke retry requests which failed due to errors. 
The retry itself fails with IndexOutOfBoundsException because ORB is using fixed length SimpleByteBuffer.

[See also this IBM Fix](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IX90187)